# Mining on my godaddy hosting

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have a hosting contract with godaddy that I don't use anymore, can I use the unused CPU and space to do bitcoin mining?

Comment: What kind of contract? On a dedicated server, this would be permitted, though completely ineffective for Bitcoin as abelenky notes below.  On a shared server, it is almost certainly forbidden by terms of service; the admins will kill your mining job when they find it, and possibly terminate your contract.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot.

CPUs and GPUs can not mine bitcoin anymore.
(they can mine all they want, but they will not find a block for literally thousands of years, nor contribute a meaningful share to a pool)

Only specially designed ASICs can do any effective bitcoin work anymore.

You may be able to find some AltCoin that you can work on.